# Sample Size of Unknown Population Traits

Tags: sample-size

Let's say that I have a list of every single hospital on the west coast (totaling 100,000) and what they charge for an ER visit per patient. If I want to find traits of the top 10% highest billers that will explain why they are in the top 10%, then what sample size will I need? I have no other traits other than hospital name and ER visit costs.

Or, is this an example of taking a sample size from a qualitative study, in which case, sample size is determined by the attainment of data saturation? In other words, saturation is reached when the researcher gathers
data to the point of diminishing returns (i.e., nothing new can be learned by gathering more data).

Comment: I think you will need to provide significantly more information here. In what context do you mean "billing high?" Do you mean highest cost or highest cost per person? What variables/traits (other than hospital name and ER cost) do you have? What do you mean by "sample size is determined by the attainment of data saturation?"

Comment: Hi Matt. I have revised my original question to address your questions.

Comment: I think that this question, in its present form, is unanswerable. You want to find traits that explain why the top 10% highest billers are in the top 10%, but you only have hospital name and ER visit costs as your traits. Obviously ER visit costs will explain high ER costs, but I imagine you're looking for other traits (like size, location, etc.) that help explain _why_ the costs are so high. If you don't have those traits (like size, location) available, then it will be impossible to see what traits influence ER visit costs.